# Using Navigation Service to redirect user to a Case Object Page in Community site

Tags: lightning-web-components, customer-community, community-builder, navigation

while I understand how one could navigate from one Standard Page to another within an LWC component, navigating to Object Page within a Community Site is very troublesome to me. I've seen this example in the eBikes Demo:

```js
handleNavigateToRecord() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT.objectApiName,
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

however, the similar approach doesn't seem to work well in my project.

```js
handleViewDetails() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.caseId,
            objectApiName: 'Case',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

First thing, my Object Page (Case Detail) has a custom base url (/case-list/*(recordId)*). The Navigation Service instead redirects to /detail/*recordId*. It results in an error: Invalid Page, which of course makes sense, because such page indeed doesn't exist. So my question is: is there something wrong in my code? Perhaps it should be handled differently?

Comment: Did you try the answer mentioned here? Please mark this as answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( Resource: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types )

```
navigateToWebPage() {
    // Navigate to a URL
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: 'http://salesforce.com'
        }
    },
    true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to comment the object API Name and try once, this may solve the issue:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-navigate-page-types.html

```
handleViewDetails() {
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: this.caseId,
        //objectApiName: 'Case', //Comment this line
        actionName: 'view'
    }
});
```

}